# Adding category archive in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

I have recently set-up my own blog on wordpress and added some 2-3 posts for a category, say A. There is also an option in the menu which has one page to give introduction of category A. This page (which gets opened by clicking Category A on menu) gives some brief description about the category. How can I make the posts related to category A appear after the description? I'm a newbie in wordpress. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a page for certain category to show brief description about it. You can add description to the category. Navigate to the Posts >> Categories >> Find the category and hit edit. Where you can see the category description.

And as always you can set the category in menu! And it will display the brief description of category and all the posts in that category! Let me know if you still need any help! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I needed: https://deductionlearning.com/category/design-patterns/  and worked perfectly with your answer. :)